# Android/Eclipse: how to have layout XML and graphic preview in the same screen

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Is there a way to have something like this:

[image]

This is achieved with two different files. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Now, I think that only Android Studio supports that feature (see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0fXuyL0xVU&t=200 ). I guess it means that it will come in Eclipse as well at some point if it is doable.

Comment: For what it is worth : I migrated my project to Android Studio as soon as it has been unveiled and I am not looking back. You just need to follow the migration guide (in Eclipse you are probably using Ant, whereas AS build system is Gradle) but it can be done in half an hour. Keeping a clean backup of your Eclipse project files is probably a good idea (I did not encounter any issue, but some people have migration troubles).